# Can we list a virtual printer in available printers without writing a driver for it

Tags: windows, driver, printers, virtual-printer

I want a virtual printer to be listed under available printers when I do a print from any application, this virtual printer would send the print data to my code for some tweaking.

And I believe I need not write a new driver for this as Microsoft itself ships Windows with the **Universal driver, Postscript and XPS driver**.

Is my belief right? Can I somehow exploit these existing drivers to create a virtual printer?

And what actually should I do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4):

Universal driver, Postscript and XPS driver.

These are rendering drivers as far as I know. A print driver has two components: the rendering component and the configuration component. Both are dlls. The rendering components are the unidrv.dll, pscript5.dll and xpsdrv.dll. Similarly, the config components are unidrvui.dll, printconfig.dll (for v4 print drivers), etc..

So I think you should write a driver using the components, you need not develop new rendering components though. But I am not sure how.